# Возможно ли раздать статический application/xml контент в nginx

Tags: nginx, http, веб-сервер

Возможно ли в nginx статически раздавать содержимое xml-файла как контент в http-ответе на http-запрос "http://localhost:5555/", причем в ответе должен присутствовать заголовок "Content-Type: application/xml" ?
Если возможно, то как надо nginx сконфигурировать для этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в простейшем случае так:

```
server {
  listen        5555;
  default_type  application/xml;
  location = / {
    alias /path/to/file.xml;
  }
}
```

или

```
server {
  listen        5555;
  default_type  application/xml;
  root /data/xml;
  location = / {
    try_files $uri /text.xml;
  }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало. Сделал запрос в SoapUI. На запрос:
GET http://localhost:5555/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5555
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

Сервер выдаёт:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 17:11:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 202
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: В браузере выдаёт тоже самое.

Comment: по заголовкам же видно, что запрос дошёл до бека. мне кажется, что постановка задачи неполна

Comment: указанный в настройках nginx'a xml-файл содержит совсем другие данные. еще хотелось получить код ответа 200.

Comment: nginx перезапущен? что говорит `nginx -t`?

Comment: nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2017/07/13 11:30:59 [emerg] 3107#3107: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
==========================
nginx -s reload я делал

Comment: прав не хватало, но и сейчас когда sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
выдаёт тот же контент (ошибка 500).

Comment: сложно что-то диагностировать не видя полного конфига nginx. из заголовков можно предположить, что запрос поступает на nginx, потом идёт на бекенд (java), а значит настоящая конфигурация nginx не соответствует написанному в ответе. выложи куда-нибудь конфиг, возможно появится ответ

Comment: Ok. nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections 768;
 # multi_accept on;
}

http{
 server {
    listen       5555;
    default_type  application/xml;
    location = / {
      alias /data/xml/;
      #root /data/xml/index.xml; 
    }
 }

 ##
 # Logging Settings
 ##

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 ##
 # Gzip Settings
 ##

 gzip on;
 gzip_disable "msie6";
}

Comment: sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
2017/07/14 15:12:26 [notice] 2508#2508: signal process started
2017/07/14 15:36:35 [alert] 2867#2867: *1 "/data/xml/index.xmlindex.html" is not a directory, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:5555"

Comment: Попробовал другой вариант запроса и конфига. Запрос на http://localhost:5555/index.xml
А в конфиге заменил строку где alias на строку root /data/xml;
В логе обнаружил новую строку: 
2017/07/14 15:49:13 [error] 2912#2912: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.xml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /index.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:5555"

Не понял почему nginx начал поиск совсем не там где указал в конфиге, но скопировав в /usr/share/nginx/html/ файл index.xml, nginx стал отвечать как надо.

Comment: Но это не то, что нужно.

Comment: `alias /data/xml/index.xml;`

Comment: 2017/07/14 18:25:18 [alert] 3379#3379: *4 "/data/xml/index.xmlindex.html" is not a directory, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:5555"

Comment: тогда так: `root /data/xml; location = / { try_files   $uri /text.xml; }`

Comment: Вот это сработало! Ура! Благодарю!!!